# Handling 304 Responses in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a 304 Not Modified response from my API server. On each request I pass an etag in `If-None-Match` by overriding `-requestWithMethod:URLString:parameters:error:` and setting the header value.

In the cases where the 304 is returned, I get no response body. In that case I fetch the cached data from my Core Data store and return it in `GET:` method completion handler.

Is there a better way returning a cached value in the response serializer, or is there another best practice I'm missing? Should I be caching the response data from the original 200 response?

Guidance welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this largely depends on your scenario, but you don't *have* to store the data in Core Data yourself.

This should work transparently with `NSURLCache` provided the server responds correctly (and it looks like it is).

The initial request has no e-tag, the server returns the response headers & body.  `NSURLCache` will notice that the response is cacheable and store it in the internal sqlite cache database.

On the next request, it will send the e-tag, server responds with 304 Not Modified, and the cache will build up the response from the cache db for you.  Your callback will receive a 200 response (you'll never see the 304).

In practice, this works transparently, but I always have to babysit it to make sure that it is caching properly, either by watching network traffic with [Charles Proxy](http://charlesproxy.com) or by inspecting the database manually (which you can find in your app's Caches directory).

Answer (score 1):

I work on an app that relies heavily on `NSURLCache`. A coworker of mine noticed this type of problem as well and solved it by adding a `AFURLConnectionOperation+CacheControlBugFix` category that will cache 304s as well. I searched a bit and I'm not sure if this is all original or if he found some of this elsewhere, but I couldn't find an original source. Here's the category, which you should import to any relevant places you want it used, or your `AppName-Prefix.pch` if you want it everywhere:

Contents of `AFURLConnectionOperation+CacheControlBugFix.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"

@interface AFURLConnectionOperation (CacheControlBugFix)
@end
```

Contents of `AFURLConnectionOperation+CacheControlBugFix.m`:

```
#import "AFURLConnectionOperation+CacheControlBugFix.h"
#import <AFDownloadRequestOperation/AFDownloadRequestOperation.h>

@implementation AFURLConnectionOperation (CacheControlBugFix)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [self swizzle:@selector(finish) replacement:@selector(da_finish)];
        [self swizzle:@selector(connection:willCacheResponse:) replacement:@selector(da_connection:willCacheResponse:)];
    });
}

- (void)da_finish {
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[AFDownloadRequestOperation class]]) {
        [self da_finish];
        return;
    }

    [self setValue:@(3) forKey:@"state"];

    // Part 1 of fix for 304 URL Caching bug.
    // We force all 200 request and 304 requests to be cached here, so that NSURLConnection's default behavior of not caching is corrected.
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) [self response];
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]] && [response statusCode] == 200) {
        NSCachedURLResponse *cachedURLResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:self.responseData];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [self.request mutableCopy];
        urlRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy; // Allow caching of all requests, even ones that have their cache policy set to not allow responses from cache

        // Make sure that we aren't here because the request was canceled. If it was, we do not want to cache.
        if ([self.error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled) {
            [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] storeCachedResponse:cachedURLResponse forRequest:urlRequest];
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AFNetworkingOperationDidFinishNotification object:self];
    });
}

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)da_connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
                  willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[AFDownloadRequestOperation class]]) {
        return [self da_connection:connection willCacheResponse:cachedResponse];
    }
    // Part 2 of fix for 304 URL Caching bug. Since we'll force all 200 requests (as well as 304 requests, which masquerade as 200 in NSURLConnection) to be cached, we don't need NSURLConnection to store it's cache in the normal way.
    return nil;
}

+ (void)swizzle:(SEL)originalSelector replacement:(SEL)swizzledSelector {
        Class class = [self class];
        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
                        originalSelector,
                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the desire to "cache 304s as well".  If it's a 304, then you already have the content in the cache.

Comment: My understanding, @BenScheirman, is that it just didn't work properly and that the data wouldn't actually come out of the cache. Hence the name of the category including `BugFix`.